# Shorthand for constructor function

Tags: ocaml

Is there any way to pass a constructor as a function?

```
type foo =
  | Foo of int
  | Bar of int

let foo x = Foo x
let bar = fun x -> Bar x
```

Is there any shorthand for the functions `foo` and `bar`? I want to pass a constructor as a function, but it seems unwieldy to write `fun x -> Bar x`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

camlspotter's answer was close enough, but in your case you want to use [Variantslib](https://github.com/janestreet/variantslib) and add `with variants` at the end of your type definition:

```
type foo = Foo of int | Bar of int with variants;;
```

gives you the following:

```
type foo = Foo of int | Bar of int
val bar : int -> foo = <fun>
val foo : int -> foo = <fun>                                                    
module Variants :
  sig
    val bar : (int -> foo) Variantslib.Variant.t
    val foo : (int -> foo) Variantslib.Variant.t
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm disappointed that I need to download a third-party library to do this, although I am impressed that it's relatively simple to add syntactic features to the language.

Answer (score 1):

Use Fieldslib: https://github.com/janestreet/fieldslib .

Adding `with fields` postfix at the type definition like:

```
type foo = | Foo of int | Bar of int with fields
```

and compile it with Fieldslib's syntax extension. It automatically generates `foo` and `bar` for you.

Comment: Fieldslib is for records, not sum types. It would work on `type foo = { foo: int; bar: int } with fields`, but not on the actual example.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Then you need something similar P4 extension to Fieldslib but for variants.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use [ppx_variants_conv](https://github.com/janestreet/ppx_variants_conv), like this:

```ml
type 'a t =
  | A of 'a
  | B of char
  | C
  | D of int * int
  [@@deriving variants]
```